# Loop fails to add missing rows

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm having a little problem with my loops. The code below is supposed to be go through the rows of `wksSource`, find matches in `wksData`, update the values and add any rows not listed in `wksData` to the bottom of the destination sheet `wksData`.

It doesn't add the missing rows but I can't see why not.

```
   Public strsourceColA As String
   Public strsourceColB As String
   Public strsourceColC As String
   Public strsourceColD As String

   'string variables for contents of database rows
    Public foundValueInA As String
    Public foundValueInB As String
    Public foundValueInC As String
    Public foundValueInD As String

   'Ranges
    Public myRange As Range
    Public myCell As Range
    Public checkCell As Range
    Public rngInput As Range
    Public rngStart As Range, rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range

    'Workbooks and sheets
     Public wkbNonconbook As Workbook
    Public wksSource As Worksheet, wksData As Worksheet

   'Long
    Public cLastFundRow As Long
    Public rowNum As Long
    Public startRow As Long
    Public endRow As Long
    Public checkRow As Long

   'Boolean
    Public blnisNCRnoMatching As Boolean
    Public blnisPartnoMatching As Boolean
    Public blnisSerialNoMatching As Boolean
    Public blnisWorkorderMatching As Boolean
    Public blnisRowMatching As Boolean





    Sub update_row()

   ' update_row Macro
   ' looks to see if a row is already included on the main database.
   '
   'set workbooks and worksheets
    Set wkbNonconbook = Application.Workbooks("ncrcon_test.xlsm")
    Set wksSource = wkbNonconbook.Sheets("080114")
    Set wksData = wkbNonconbook.Sheets("Data_base")

    startRow = 4
    checkRow = startRow
    endRow = wksSource.Range("A1").Offset(wksSource.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngInput = wksSource.Range("A" & startRow & ":A" & endRow)

    For Each checkCell In rngInput.Cells


        ' Initialize strings to with column contents to be matched from update/source sheet
        strsourceColA = checkCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
        strsourceColB = checkCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        strsourceColC = checkCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        strsourceColD = checkCell.Offset(0, 2).Value

        cLastFundRow = wksData.Range("A1").Offset(wksData.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row

        ' Initialize search range

        Set myRange = wksData.Range("A4:A" & cLastFundRow)

        ' Iterate over given Excel range in database
            For Each myCell In myRange.Cells

            foundValueInA = myCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
            foundValueInB = myCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            foundValueInC = myCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            foundValueInD = myCell.Offset(0, 3).Value

            blnisNCRnoMatching = (searchKeyA = foundValueInA)
            blnisPartnoMatching = (searchKeyB = foundValueInB)
            blnisSerialNoMatching = (searchKeyC = foundValueInC)
            blnisWorkorderMatching = (searchKeyD = foundValueInD)
            blnisRowMatching = blnisNCRnoMatching And blnisPartnoMatching And      blnisSerialNoMatching And blnisWorkorderMatching
                    'check if row needs to be updated
                If (blnisRowMatching) Then
                    checkRow = checkCell.Row
                    Set rngSource = wksSource.Range("A" & checkRow & ":AD" & checkRow)
                    rngSource.Copy
                    rowNum = myCell.Row
                    Set rngDest = wksData.Range("A" & rowNum & ":AD" & rowNum)
                    rngDest.PasteSpecial
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next myCell

            'If row is missing from database then add it
            If (blnisRowMatching = False) And (rowNum = cLastFundRow) Then

                cLastFundRow = cLastFundRow + 1
                Set myRange = wksData.Range("A4:AD" & cLastFundRow)
                checkRow = myCell.Row
                Set rngSource = wksSource.Range("A" & checkRow & ":AD" & checkRow)
                rngSource.Copy
                rowNum = myCell.Row + 1
                Set rngDest = wksData.Range("A" & rowNum & ":AD" & rowNum)
                rngDest.PasteSpecial
            End If
      Next checkCell
   End Sub
```

How might I fix this please?

Comment: Is there a unique identifier in any of the columns?  If it's possible to use `Vlookup` instead of nested `For` loops, I would recommend doing so.  If you must do it the way you have listed, can you describe what happens?  Are there any errors, or does nothing happen at all?  If nothing happens you should try stepping through the code and ensure that your variables (especially your booleans) are being set as you expect.

Comment: No unique indentifier, as there will be multiple serial numbers with the same NCRno, partno and workorder, and the serial numbers will be unique to that particular batch. The combination of the values of those columns is the only indentifier. I would love to be able to use Vloopup as it would be much easier. Currently there aren't errors but it is not copying any new rows into wksData... and takes over 20 mins to run. I'm going to try it with a smaller data set in the morning and see what it is actually doing. A way of avoiding for loops would be great though.

Comment: Just tested it this morning using a sample data set. Doesn't do anything. I have stepped through the code, and it does go into the loops just doesn't do anything. is there an easy way of finding what it is setting the variables as?

Comment: If you mouse over the variable, you should be able to see its value in the Immediate window. This looks different depending on what version of Excel you're using, but take a look at [this article](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) for more info.  You can also set a MsgBox to pop up and display the value of the variable.

Comment: Ah, super. Got the macro working on test data, and it adds rows and updates as needed. Only it takes a long time. Would it be quicker to use arrays to store, compare, update and add row values? I'm currently using for each loops to assign values.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you were able to correct the errors.  For speed, you'll be limited without having a unique identifier to search for.  You should be able to use Match or Find to match one criterion (NCRno or part no for example) and then only run your For loop that checks all values on those rows only.  Also take a look at [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248759/how-can-i-reduce-the-process-time-with-excel-vba/21248906#21248906).  There's some good information about general steps to speed up VBA code, including turning off screen updating and calculations while your code is running.

Comment: Could I concatenate the 4 column values and use that as unique indentifier? Or is that a bad idea? The match or Find sounds more reliable from what I've seen on stackoverflow. I had spotted your linked answer already and will work it in.

Comment: That's an interesting thought and not a bad idea.  I'm not sure how much time it would save though.  You'd have to loop through, concatenate the values, and then `Find` the new value.  If you're able to keep the concatenated values in a new column so that they don't have to be created each time, it would probably save time.